# letter/word guessing game in python

Tags: python

*background*

I'm attempting to code a basic letter game in python. In the game, the computer moderator picks a word out of a list of possible words. Each player (computer AI and human) is shown a series of blanks, one for each letter of the word. Each player then guesses a letter and a position, and are told one of the following:

That letter belongs in that position (the best outcome)
That letter is in the word, but not in that position
That letter is not in any of the remaining blank spaces
When the word has been fully revealed, the player to guess the most letters correctly wins a point. The computer moderator picks another word and starts again. The first player to five points wins the game. In the basic game, both players share the same set of blanks they're filling in, so the players benefit from each other's work.

*question*

I'm working on the computer AI portion right now (bottom of the code). I want it to select a random letter from a list of letters that HAVEN'T already been guessed. What's the best way to do this?

```
import random

#set initial values
player1points= 0
ai= 0
userCorrectLetters= ''
aiCorrectLetters=''
wrongPlace=''
wrongLetters=''
correctLetters = ''
notInWord = ''
endGame = False
alreadyGuessed = 'a'
userGuessPosition = 0

###import wordlist, create mask
with open('/Users/jamyn/Documents/workspace/Lab3/Lab3/wordlist.txt') as wordList:
    secretWord = random.choice(wordList.readlines()).strip()

print (secretWord) 
mask = '_'  * len(secretWord)
for i in range (len(secretWord)):
    if secretWord[i] in correctLetters:
        mask = mask[:i] + secretWord[i] + mask [i+1:]
for letter in mask:
    print (letter, end='')
    print ()

print ()


def addAlreadyGuessed():
    alreadyGuessed= userCorrectLetters + aiCorrectLetters + wrongLetters + correctLetters

def displayGame():
    print ('letters are in word but not in correct location:', wrongPlace)
    print ('letters not in word:', notInWord)
    ##asks the user for a guess, assigns input to variable
def getUserGuess(alreadyGuessed):


    while True:
        print ('enter your letter')
        userGuess = input ()
        userGuess= userGuess.lower()
        if len(userGuess) != 1:
            print ('please enter only one letter')
        elif userGuess in alreadyGuessed:
            print ('that letter has already been guessed. try again')
        elif userGuess not in 'abcdefjhijklmnopqrstuvwxyz':
            print ('only letters are acceptable guesses. try again.')
        else:
            return userGuess

def newGame():
    print ('yay. that was great. do you want to play again? answer yes or no.')
    return input().lower().startswith('y')


userTurn=True     
while userTurn == True:
    print ('which character place would you like to guess. Enter number?')
    userGuessPosition = int(input())

    slice1 = userGuessPosition - 1  
    print (secretWord)  


    ##player types in letter
    guess = getUserGuess(wrongLetters + correctLetters)
    if guess== (secretWord[slice1:userGuessPosition]):
        correctLetters = correctLetters + guess
        print ('you got it right! ')
        break
    elif guess in secretWord:
            userCorrectLetters = userCorrectLetters + guess 
            correctLetters = correctLetters + guess
            print ('that letter is in the word, but not in that position')
            break
    else:
            wrongLetters = wrongLetters + guess
            print ('nope. that letter is not in the word')
            break

print ('its the computers turn')

aiTurn=True

while aiTurn == True:
    aiGuess=random.choice('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
    print (aiGuess)
```

Comment: I need to figure out how to subtrack letters from a list every time the letter guessed is part of the word. IE, start with list as [abcdefghiklmnopqrstuvwxyz] and if the user guesses an "a" then the list would be modified to read [bcdefg....etc]. Then I should be able to use random.choice to have the AI select its guess from this list.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use pythons set, keep a set containing all 26 letters, and a set of the ones guessed, and just ask for the elements in the large set that are not in the larger set http://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html ... then pull your random choice from that result

```
allletters = set(list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))
usedletters = set() # update this as you go
availletters = allletters.difference(usedletters) #s - t    new set with elements in s but not in t
```

to print the sets out nicely, you can do

```
print sorted(availletters)
```

or

```
print ', '.join(sorted(availletters))
```

to answer your followup on adding guesses, here is a quick example

```
allletters = set(list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))
usedletters = set() # update this as you go
while( len(usedletters) != len(allletters) ):
    guessedletter = raw_input("pick a letter")
    availletters = allletters.difference(usedletters)
    usedletters.update(guessedletter)
```

you could also just have one list and subtract letters as they've been guessed, such as:

```
allletters = set(list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'))
while( len(usedletters) != len(allletters) ):
    guessedletter = raw_input("pick a letter")
    allletters.difference_update(guessedletter)
```

Comment: hmm... i'm getting an error---"set object does not support indexing"

Comment: and how would you suggest i update the set of available numbers as i go along?

Comment: right, if you would like to index, you need to cast it back to a list. 'list(myset)'

Comment: @John, what set of available numbers (what variable are you referring to?) ... as a general comment, you can use '.update' and '.difference_update' to add or remove an element from a set as an in-place operation

Comment: thanks for your help @pyInTheSky. I see where you're going with that approach, but i don't seem to be able to use random.choice anymore to select from that list..

Comment: #you need to cast the set to a list when you make the choice: >>> a = set( list('abcde') )
>>> random.choice(list(a))
'e'